# grunt.js (a node.js build tool) is not creating directories or files. is it permission related?

Tags: javascript, macos, node.js, permissions, gruntjs

We are using grunt.js as a build tool.

On one of our development machines (MacOS Mountain Lion), grunt is running but does not seem to create any files and directories.

Another thing which was different on that specific machine is that when we used the NPM to install some plugins for grunt we had to use `sudo npm`, otherwise we had permission errors.

We've checked the permissions on the parent directory and tried different things - nothing seemed to work. NodeJs still does not create any files or directories.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Apparently the html-compressor grunt plugin requires grunt 1.4 as a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds a lot like a permission problem. Navigate to your directory in question and then try
`ls -l` in your terminal. Should look something like this:

[image: permissions example]

If your directory does not have similar permissions, change them to, for example, `chmod 775 mydir`. Use `sudo` if needed.

Comment: not at all. we think it was a faulty module. we're not sure. we noticed that the node_modules was missing. when we copied it the html-compressor module said something about a missing "_" dependency. we noticed that the new html-compressor plugin only works with grunt 1.4 which was not yet released. we downloaded an older version of the module and everything works now.

Comment: Thanks, so it was a dependency problem.